# Why doesn't TypeScript narrow type after a map that can only return the narrow type?

Tags: typescript

In the code below I would expect the find function to return `undefined | BufferEncoding`, the same type as the Map has. But `undefined | string` is returned. How come?

```
  const chartdetToFsEncodings = new Map<string, BufferEncoding>([
    ["UTF-8", "utf8"],
    ["UTF-16LE", "utf16le"],
  ]);

  const supportedEncoding = analyse(buffer)
    .map((match) => match.name)
    .find((name) =>
      chartdetToFsEncodings.get(name)
    ) as BufferEncoding;
```

I tried setting the Map as const, but got some syntax error.

```
  const chartdetToFsEncodings = new Map<string, BufferEncoding>([
    ["UTF-8", "utf8"],
    ["UTF-16LE", "utf16le"],
  ]) as const;
```

Comment: What is the type of the expression `analyse(buffer).map((match) => match.name)`? What is the expected return type of the function given to `find`? Does `find` expect a function that returns a value of type `boolean`?

Comment: As a side-note, I do not know whether there is any place or way to look up the TypeScript types for the methods of built-in objects. There is of course MDN, such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find , but that does not include TypeScript types as far as I know.

Comment: Seems that the function passed to `Array.find` does not have return type `boolean`, but "truthy"/"falsy"...

Comment: @Terry: Yes, it is a simple union type from a third party lib. What would be my best solution in this case?

Comment: @MelvinWM: Yes, that is correct. Does that matter for typing?

Comment: @user1283776 I would guess the typing of the expressions are as follows: `analyse(...)
    .map(...): Array<string>` ; `analyse(...)
    .map(...).find(...): string | undefined`. Simply because `find` does not transform the element type, it only uses the passed-in function to check "truthiness" of elements with. Do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

The issue boils down to the incorrect use of `Array.prototype.find`. The method acts like a filter, but returns only the first element in the array for which the predicate returns true. In that case, it can either return an element from the mapped array, from `.map(match => match.name)`, which is typed as `string`, or `undefined`.

If you want to get an array of `BufferEncoding` instead, you can do it directly in `.map()` callback:

```
const supportedEncoding = analyse(buffer)
    .map((match) => chartdetToFsEncodings.get(match.name))
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` method is used by an `string[]`, so it will return `string | undefined`. If you want to have `BufferEncoding | undefined`, this is the easiest way:

```js
const supportedEncoding = analyse(buffer)
    .map((match) => match.name)
    .find((name): name is BufferEncoding =>
      chartdetToFsEncodings.get(name) !== undefined
    );
```